# Undefined reference error C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i accessed a static function(funA()) in class A (all function in this class is static) but getting Undefined reference error. I included header

Please help.

```
// H file
Class A
{

 static void funA();
};

// Cpp file
void A::funA() {  }

Accessed in class B
void B::funB()
{
 A::funA()
}
```

Comment: Are you actually, *defining* the question on the implementation file?

Comment: Post the actual code and the actual error.

Comment: please post the code of class `A` and how you call the function!

Comment: Provide a minimal example that you expect to compile and link, but does not compile or link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included the right `.lib` file, if necessary?

Comment: i didnt include . lib file. Only included classA header file

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have something like this on your header:

```
// a.h
class A {
   static void funA();
};

// a.cpp
void
A::funA() {
    // do something on your function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your edit it seems you're missing the `public:` part before `static void FunA()`.. did you just forget to edit it in or maybe it's really missing in your .cpp?

Answer (score 0):

You should always initizalize static functions and variables in cpp file before using

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have double declaration in your code, because this would give you a compiler error.